# Node JS Puppeteer: Refresh page elements after click without reloading webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm looking to get the list of songs on a web page under a particular genre. In my code, I'm using puppeteer to select a filter option which should change the data held in the elements where the list of songs appear.
Upon running my code, the webpage displays the newly selected genre but doesn't update the list of songs. I tried `page.reload()` but that took me back to the default webpage before clicking the filters.

***EDIT:***
To provide more detail, I'm trying to scrape genius.com to get a list of all rap songs. I've created a work around which uses threading but it only works sometimes and I've tried rearranging the code a few times but nothing seems to have worked.

```
console.log("Rap songs");
    const filter = await page.$$(
      ".SquareManySelects__Option-sc-1kktot3-5.eLlkRP"
    );

    
    for (let i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
      const name = await filter[i].$eval(
        ".SquareSelectOption__Container-h4rr3o-0.gMvRPT",
        (v) => v.textContent
      );

      if (name == "Rap") {
        console.log({
          name,
        });

        // ***************** WORIKING WITH THREADING ERROR *********************
        await Promise.all([
          page.waitForSelector(
            ".SquareSelectOption__Container-h4rr3o-0.gMvRPT"
          ),
          filter[i].click(),
        ]);

        // ***************** WORIKING WITH THREADING ERROR *********************
        break;
      }
    }
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000);

    //  TESTING
    const reviewElements = await page.$$(
      ".ChartSongdesktop__CoverAndTitle-sc-18658hh-0.jzapEV"
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < reviewElements.length; i++) {
      const name = await reviewElements[i].$eval(
        ".ChartSongdesktop__Title-sc-18658hh-3.fODYHn",
        (v) => v.textContent
      );

      console.log({
        name,
      });
    }
    console.log("Done");
  },
```

Comment: On the website, does the URL changes when you apply the filter?

Comment: @FurkanAtılgan No the URL does not change.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help without the actual page to experiment with. It could be pretty much anything.

Comment: @ggorlen Check the edit to the post

Comment: Thanks, but what's the URL of the page? It's a waste of our time for me to show you how to scrape a page from genius.com, only to turn out it's the wrong thing. It's a bit weird to use `waitForSelector` and `click` in the same `Promise.all`. That looks like a race condition that should be serialized.

Comment: @ggorlen The URL is: https://genius.com/ . The info I am trying to get is literally on the homepage.  How would I go about serializing this? 
Disclaimer: I'm new to Javascript and webscraping